# install4j: can't create quick launch icon

Tags: install4j, quicklaunch

I have an "Additional confirmations" screen, with 2 "checkbox" form components:

- Add a desktop link (linked to the boolean "createDesktopLinkAction")
- Add a quick launch icon (linked to the boolean "createQuicklaunchIconAction").

At the end of the installation, I have 2 actions:

- Create desktop icon (linked to the boolean "createQuicklaunchIconAction")
- Create quick launch icon (linked to the boolean "createQuicklaunchIconAction").

  They are both attached to the launcher.

The desktop icon is created, but the quick launch icon doesn't, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Create a quick launch icon" action only works up to Windows Vista. After that, there is no quick launch bar anymore, the task bar is a different entity. We will likely remove this action in install4j 7.